# Save gmsh-generated nodes and elements to std::vector or other container

Tags: c++, api, mesh, finite-element-analysis

I am using the [gmsh](https://gmsh.info/) C++ API as a part of a larger optimization project. All I need gmsh for is to mesh some polygons at every iteration in order to conduct a finite element analysis.

According to the [tutorials](https://gitlab.onelab.info/gmsh/gmsh/-/blob/master/tutorial/c++/t1.cpp), once a mesh instance is generated, it can be save to a `.msh` file with the `write()` method, e.g.:

```cpp
gmsh::initialize();
// ...
// Geometry definition
// ...
gmsh::model::mesh::generate(2);
gmsh::write("myfile.msh");
```

And in the `.msh` file I can see all the nodes, elements, and other information.

Now, as I mentioned above, I only need gmsh's output to conduct some analysis with some functions that I've already written, and to which I only need to feed a `std::vector` or `Eigen::Vector` containing the nodes and the vectors.

One (inefficient) way to do so is, of course, to export the `.msh` file and then parse it to create a `std::vector` out of the nodal information. I am looking for a way to just access the nodes and elements so that I can store them in a `std::vector` (or `Eigen::Vector`) directly.

Is there a way to avoid dumping everything to a local file? I know I could reverse engineer this operation by going through the `write()` method and looking at how the nodal information is saved to a file, but:

1. I feel like there must be some API function that serves exactly this purpose
2. I'd rather avoid going through the huge source files to figure out this information myself, since I need this software to be completed as soon as possible